# Correct way of implementing PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices

Tags: spring-security, remember-me

I want to implement `remember-me` functionality using `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices`, I tried with the following entity:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "persistent_logins")
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PersistentLogin implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "series", unique = true, nullable = false,length = 64)
    private String series;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "username",length = 64,nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "token",length = 64,nullable = false)
    private String token;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "last_userd",nullable = false)
    private Date lastUsed;

}
```

and the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/register", "/confirm", "/post_register").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                .and()
                    // omitting login and logout related configs
                .and()
                    .rememberMe()
                        .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                        .rememberMeServices(persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());

        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }    

    @Bean// browser remember me
    PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(){
        PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices p =
                new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(
                        REMEMBER_ME_KEY,
                        userDetailsService,
                        new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl()
                );
        p.setCookieName(JSESSIONID);
        p.setTokenValiditySeconds(24 * 60 * 60);
        return p;
    }

    @Bean
    RememberMeAuthenticationFilter rememberMeAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        return new RememberMeAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices());
    }

    @Bean
    RememberMeAuthenticationProvider rememberMeAuthenticationProvider(){
        return new RememberMeAuthenticationProvider(REMEMBER_ME_KEY);
    }

}
```

with the above configuration I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl.getTokenForSeries(JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl.java:87)
```

with full StackTrace given bellow:

```
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583521+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583522+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl.getTokenForSeries(JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl.java:87) ~[sp
ring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583528+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.processAutoLoginCookie(PersistentTokenBa
sedRememberMeServices.java:104) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583529+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices.autoLogin(AbstractRememberMeServices.java:136) ~[spr
ing-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583529+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:98)
 ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583530+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEA
SE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583531+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:
170) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583531+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEA
SE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583532+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.
3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583532+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEA
SE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583532+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.jav
a:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583533+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEA
SE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583533+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.ja
r!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583534+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEA
SE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583534+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.REL
EASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583536+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE
]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583536+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEA
SE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583537+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEAS
E.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583537+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE
]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583537+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEA
SE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583538+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-sec
urity-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583538+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEA
SE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583544+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.
java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583545+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE
]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583545+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEA
SE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583546+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.
0.3.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583546+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELE
ASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583547+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4
.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583547+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEA
SE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583548+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]

2020-03-25T06:02:10.583548+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583548+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.
RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583549+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE
]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583550+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]

2020-03-25T06:02:10.583550+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583550+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar
!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583550+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE
]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583551+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]

2020-03-25T06:02:10.583551+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583551+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.
0.4.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583552+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE
]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583552+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]

2020-03-25T06:02:10.583553+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583561+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/
:5.0.4.RELEASE]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583562+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE
]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583562+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]

2020-03-25T06:02:10.583562+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583563+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583564+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583565+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583569+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583569+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583570+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583570+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:677) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583570+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583571+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583571+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583574+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583575+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583575+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583576+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583576+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583577+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar!/:8.5.28]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583577+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242-heroku]
2020-03-25T06:02:10.583578+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-03-25T06:02:10.712684+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-03-25 06:02:10.647 ERROR 4 --- [io-22186-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherSer
vlet] threw exception
```

Question is: What is the correct way of implementing `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices`? I have searched the Net, found examples and followed them, but that did not work as expected. Is there something I'm missing?